# RenderScript crashes app with "Missing .rs.global_entries"

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I am using a RenderScript to rotate set of images. The application crashes abruptly with  Fatal signal 11. There are 100s of "D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object" messages in the log. Also see significant memory increase as well.
What is the cause for this? How do solve it?

I am using Samsung Galexy tab with android 4.4.2. I have listed Gradle, Rs , Java and logcat output below.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 21
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true


 #pragma version(1)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.models)

rs_allocation inImage;
int inWidth;
int inHeight;

uchar4 __attribute__ ((kernel)) rotate_270_clockwise (uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    uint32_t inX  = inWidth - 1 - y;
    uint32_t inY = x;
    const uchar4 *out = rsGetElementAt(inImage, inX, inY);
    return *out;
}

uchar4 __attribute__ ((kernel)) rotate_180_clockwise (uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

    uint32_t inX = inWidth - 1 - x;
    uint32_t inY = inHeight - 1 - y;

    const uchar4 *out = rsGetElementAt(inImage, inX, inY);
    return *out;
}

uchar4 __attribute__ ((kernel)) rotate_90_clockwise (uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    uint32_t inX = y;
    uint32_t inY = inHeight - 1 - x;

    const uchar4 *out = rsGetElementAt(inImage, inX, inY);
    return *out;
}

uchar4 __attribute__ ((kernel)) rotate_0_clockwise (uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    uint32_t inX = x;
    uint32_t inY =  y;

    const uchar4 *out = rsGetElementAt(inImage, inX, inY);
    return *out;
}
```

Java code

```
public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Activity activity, int angle, boolean recycle) {
    Bitmap target = null;
    try {
        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(activity, RenderScript.ContextType.DEBUG);
        ScriptC_rotator script = new ScriptC_rotator(rs);
        script.set_inWidth(bitmap.getWidth());
        script.set_inHeight(bitmap.getHeight());
        Allocation sourceAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap,
                Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
        if (recycle)
            bitmap.recycle();
        script.set_inImage(sourceAllocation);

        //270 and 90
        int targetHeight = bitmap.getWidth();
        int targetWidth = bitmap.getHeight();
        if (angle == 180 || angle == 0) {
            targetHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            targetWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        }

        Bitmap.Config config = bitmap.getConfig();
        target = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, config);
        final Allocation targetAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, target,
                Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
        if (angle == 90)
            script.forEach_rotate_90_clockwise(targetAllocation, targetAllocation);
        else if (angle == 180)
            script.forEach_rotate_180_clockwise(targetAllocation, targetAllocation);
        else if (angle == 270)
            script.forEach_rotate_270_clockwise(targetAllocation, targetAllocation);
        else
            script.forEach_rotate_0_clockwise(targetAllocation, targetAllocation);

        targetAllocation.copyTo(target);
        rs.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("myApp", "rotateBitmap- render script " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return target;
}
```

Log

```
 04-19 22:04:02.219  30377-30377/com.champ D/myApp﹕ processActionUp-scaleDetector.isInProgress()
    04-19 22:04:04.259  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:04.259  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:04.269  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:04.269  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:04.279  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:04.279  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:04.289  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:04.319  30377-30377/com.champ D/myApp﹕ processActionUp
    04-19 22:04:04.319  30377-30377/com.champ D/myApp﹕ processActionUp-scaleDetector.isInProgress()
    04-19 22:04:07.389  30377-30377/com.champ D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2335K, 9% free 33300K/36444K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
    04-19 22:04:07.389  30377-30377/com.champ I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 33.607MB for 320336-byte allocation
    04-19 22:04:07.409  30377-30377/com.champ D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 9% free 33609K/36760K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
    04-19 22:04:07.419  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.479  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.489  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.489  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.499  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.509  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.509  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.519  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.529  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.529  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:07.559  30377-30377/com.champ D/myApp﹕ processActionUp
    04-19 22:04:07.559  30377-30377/com.champ D/myApp﹕ processActionUp-scaleDetector.isInProgress()
    04-19 22:04:11.709  30377-30377/com.champ D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1496K, 12% free 32489K/36760K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
    04-19 22:04:11.759  30377-30377/com.champ D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 11% free 32843K/36760K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
    04-19 22:04:11.759  30377-30377/com.champ I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 33.221MB for 383696-byte allocation
    04-19 22:04:11.779  30377-30386/com.champ D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 33217K/37136K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
    04-19 22:04:11.779  30377-30761/com.champ D/RenderScript﹕ Missing .rs.global_entries from shared object
    04-19 22:04:11.789  30377-30763/com.champ A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x66082000 (code=1), thread 30763 (AsyncTask #4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop creating a RenderScript context (android.RenderScript), and loading the Script (i.e. ScriptC_rotator) on every single call to one of your rotate*() functions. You should be caching these objects as it is not lightweight to use either. This should cut down on that logging, as well as reduce memory fragmentation (because you keep loading/unloading the Scripts).

The SIGSEGV is a bit more confusing, but it is likely because of an out-of-bounds memory access in your .rs file. I see that you are creating a DEBUG context. Was that in place when you captured this log, or is that something that go added later? Considering the swap for width/height because of rotation, I think that you are using bad Y/X values in the .rs kernels. Consider using rsDebug to print out that indices you are writing into, and you will probably see where it ultimately fails (and that it is indeed out of bounds).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your comments helped me to Improve the performance  tremendously. The crash is because of the width and height. I resolved that too. Thanks